# How to ask a person how long he has been working in an office?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, perfect-constructions

Context : Let say, I have just joined to a company and I want to ask my new friend how long he has been working here.

**Using Present perfect:**

> How long have you worked here ?

Or

**using Present perfect continuous tense ?**

> How long have you been working here ?

According to the image below:

[image: diagram showing past/present/future timeline]

Image credit: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html

So my answer is using `present perfect continuous` because I think he started in the past and he's still working at that office now. Am I right ?

Please include the reason on your answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either would be correct in this context.

Generally, the present perfect simple tense describes what has been happened *so far*, while the present perfect continuous suggests that something is *ongoing* or *unfinished*. The distinction isn't strong enough in this question to make a big difference.

Looking at two possible responses to the question might highlight the differences better.

> (present perfect simple) **I've worked here five years** and I've loved every moment of it!
>
> (present perfect continuous) **I've been working here five years**, but it's only recently that I was transferred to this office.

Similarly, one could say:

> (present perfect simple) **He's worked three hours today** [he might work more, or he might go home after this].
>
> (present perfect continuous) **He's been working the whole morning** [and he's still not done with his work].

Comment: I don't get it "I've been working here five years, but it's only recently that I was transferred to this office." Does "here" means "same company" but he's transferred to branch office (different office) ? Can you tell me the differences between perfect and perfect continous ?

Comment: Right, "here" means "this organization/company/firm..." while "this office" means "this particular location out of the many offices we have". The difference is that PPS implies "I've worked here for X years" without saying whether that state will continue. By contrast, PPC implies "I've worked here for X years" and strongly suggests that it will continue.

Comment: So,can I tell `perfect is not necessarily to continue` BUT `perfect continues is definitely will continue` ?